# Can I set the ButtonUI for only a subset of JButton classes?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I want to create a button class and use a ButtonUI to render it instead of overriding the paint component method. I do not want to use this ButtonUI for ALL JButtons. Is that possible?  I've only ever seen `UIManager.put("ButtonUI","MyCustomButtonUI")`, but does this affect ALL JButton rendering? Is it possible to limit the scope of the put operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JButton.setUI(ButtonUI)` sets the UI for just one `JButton`.  Use that in conjunction with a factory:

```
public static JButton createStyledButton(String text) {
   JButton button = new JButton(text);
   button.setUI(STYLE_UI);
   return button;
}
```

**EDIT**: Or, since you say it's constant for a certain subclass, just call `setUI()` from the constructor for that subclass.

**Another alternative** might be to override the method `getUIClassID()` in your subclass.  This will *probably* allow you to still use the `UIManager` to choose which style to use, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can, in your [ButtonUI](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ButtonUI.html) class, check the real component class being given to you and only override default behaviour for our desired subclass, through instanceof or any other mechanism.

But, if you, like me, don't like repeated calls to `instanceof` use another trick. As your button subclasses JButton, it also subclasses JButton and AbstractButton, allowing you to call `AbstractButton#setUI` in your constructor or somewhere else, allowing a specific renderer, totally distinct from LnF application.